# Edit the Display Name for a contact in Contacts.app

Tags: mac, contacts, contacts.app

First off: I'm mass printing envelopes. I export my contacts (from Contacts.app) to vCard, then convert them to CSV, before using MS Word's built-in mass-mailing tool.

In my contacts, I've found it to be easier to make an individual contact for each person, so I can keep their email addresses and phone numbers sorted nicely.  However, I'd like to have my cards addressed to the family, not just the individual.

### TL;DR:

*I'd like a program that will combine the spouse's name with the main contact's name, and store it either in the existing `FN` field of the card, or else add a new field (such as `famName`, etc.).  I'd prefer a UI-based program, if available, but having found nothing that has this functionality built in, I wouldn't mind a simple regex-based script.*

---

### Example:

Contact:

[image: Contact Example]

Export to vCard:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//Mac OS X 10.11.2//EN
N:Johnson;;;;
FN:Johnson
TEL;type=HOME;type=VOICE;type=pref:##########
ADR;type=HOME;type=pref:;;################;##########;##;#####;
NOTE:CLCC
CATEGORIES:Address Book
X-ABUID:6D98572D-5520-4E6E-9474-3294827D4D39:ABPerson
END:VCARD
```

You'll notice the two separate fields, `N`, and `FN`.  The `N` field seems to be each part of the name, separated by semicolons.  The `FN` field seems to be the display name (Although it probably stands for Full Name).  It would be wonderful if I could find a way edit that field through the UI, but I can't find it.

> **Edit:**   If there is a spouse's name in the card, the card will look like this:
>
> ```
> BEGIN:VCARD
> VERSION:3.0
> PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//Mac OS X 10.11.2//EN
> N:Doe;John;;;
> FN:John Doe
> ADR;type=HOME;type=pref:;;##############;#########;##;#####;
> item1.X-ABRELATEDNAMES;type=pref:Rebbecca Doe
> item1.X-ABLabel:_$!<Spouse>!$_
> CATEGORIES:Christmas Cards Set 2 2015
> X-ABUID:3FD45D07-093E-446E-AB4B-3767FDEC1A15:ABPerson
> END:VCARD
> ```

---

### Soooo:

Is there a way to Edit the Display Name (`FN`) through the Contacts.app UI?
*If not,* is there a way to edit it through *any* UI?
*If not,* is there an easy way to edit it programmatically? (I have access to Windows, too...)
*If not,* I'm open to *any* way to edit it programmatically...  :)

Thank you all!

---

> **Edit:**   After thinking about it for a while, I think an even better/easier way would be to take the spouse (first) name in the
> contact, and add it to the display name.

*e.g.*
First Name = John
Last Name = Doe
Spouse = Rebbecca Doe

Full Name (Display Name) = John & Rebbecca Doe

Comment: Maybe not a perfect solution, however you can add a Nickname field to any contact.  This would allow you to manually edit and set the nickname to the joint name.  You could then use the nickname field in Word to achieve the result you are looking for.   And this would be done manually through the UI.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I already use the nickname field in some cases.  I'd rather just export the vCard (like I have to do anyways to convert to CSV), and edit the vCard.

Comment: I think maybe the best option would be to write an AppleScript that would edit the vCard.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help you somehow. Download **Bento** for Mac from [here](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11182/~/software-update%3A-bento-4.1.2-for-mac). Unfortunately, it's not supported by FileMaker anymore, but anyway it works fine even on El Capitan (I use it here :)) Open it and it will ask permission to access your Contacts. Allow it. This it will open very convenient interface for mass editing your Contacts in list and/or individually with ability to add your own fields. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good option.  It has a lot of customizability.  I particularly like that you can export directly to CSV or Excel. (+1)  If no better options come up, I think I'll use this one.  However, what I'm really looking for is something that will simply auto-combine the spouse's name with the main contact's name.